# flash - how do you add drop shadow filter without lagging on iOS?

Tags: flash

I added a couple of drop shadow filters to my objects in flash.

It lagged A LOT in my iPhone.

So my question is, is there a work-around for this issue? I need shadows for my objects in order for them to look good, but it lags to much on the iPhone.

Comment: If it's not a dynamic shadow you can put the movieclip into a symbol then do cacheAsBitmap. Worst case you can always convert the image to an actual png.

Comment: Bitmap does reduce lag, but however it won't solve the issue as I need the drop shadow filter's moving shadow effect.

Comment: What about making a png shadow and moving it around behind your object to make it appear like a casted shadow? It's more work, but that's flash on ios for ya :/

Comment: Oh, I meant the shadow kinda forms into the object, so if the object moves, the shadow reshapes itself to match and stay into the angle of the shadow view. So that wouldn't work out.